# How do I find the modulus of a sum of vectors which is part of a triangle embedded in a quarter a circle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

In the figure from below, calculate the modulus of $\vec{x}+\vec{y}$. $P$ is tangential point. Show the answer in terms of $R$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&1R\\
2.&0.41R\\
3.&0.59R\\
4.&1.41R\\
5.&2.12R\\
\end{array}$

The only thing which I was able to spot here was to establish that

$x=\frac{(R+a)\sqrt{2}}{2}+a$

$y=\frac{(R+a)\sqrt{2}}{2}+a$

But this doesn't seem very convincing to me. How exactly can I use the vector decomposition in this set of vectors?.

Answer (score 0):

Let ${\vec x}$ start from $A$ and ${\vec y}$ start from $B$. Let the right angle be at $O$.

$${\vec x}=\vec {AO}+\vec {OP}$$

$${\vec y}=\vec {BO}+\vec {OP}$$

$$\vec x+\vec y=\vec {AO}+\vec {BO} +2\vec {OP}$$
$$\vec x+\vec y=-\sqrt 2\vec {OP}+2\vec {OP}$$
$$|\vec x+\vec y|=(2-\sqrt 2)R$$
$$|\vec x+\vec y|=0.59R$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec{x} = \vec{XP}$, $\vec{y} = \vec{YP} $ and write the vectors  $\vec{X}=(0,R)$, $\vec{Y}=(R,0)$ and $\vec{P}=(\frac R{\sqrt2}, \frac R{\sqrt2})$. Then,

$$\vec{x} = \vec{P} -\vec{X}=(\frac R{\sqrt2}, \frac R{\sqrt2}-R),\>\>\>\>\>\>\>
\vec{y} = \vec{P} -\vec{Y}=(\frac R{\sqrt2}-R, \frac R{\sqrt2}) $$

Evaluate

$$\vec{x}+\vec{y} = (\sqrt2 R-R, \sqrt2 R-R)$$

Thus, the modulus is $\sqrt{2(\sqrt2 R-R)^2}=(2-\sqrt2)R=0.59R$.